# I can't get npm on debian

Tags: node.js, debian

when I check "npm" console returns "command not found"
So I did "apt-get install npm" but console returns me "packets not found"

How can I install dependencies now if I can't run npm ?
thx

Comment: Have you installed Node.js on the system?

Comment: Which debian do you use? Did you already updated your package list? Could u install nodejs?

Comment: yes I have install nodejs (version = 4.8.2) I use debian 9

Comment: root@ns3308705:/dev/www/portofolio/chatNodeJs# apt-get install npm
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet npm

Comment: translation : Reading Package Lists ... Done Building Dependency Tree Reading Status Information ... Fact E: Can not find package npm

Comment: 4.8.2 is a very old version, latest lts is 10.16.3. How did you installed that version?

Comment: I did "apt-get install nodejs" :/

Comment: did you already tried `sudo apt update` to fetch the latest package list?

Comment: yes apt update and upgrade are done

Comment: finally it' work, I use a method with curl command

Answer (score -2):

uninstall the previous one and install it back, then try that command again

Comment: i had a similar issue it said npm command not found so i reinstall it again and tried apt-get install npm